# Convert string to int array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

How do I convert a String: `s = '23534'` to an array as such: `a = [2,3,5,3,4]`

Is there a way to iterate over the chars in ruby and convert each of them `to_i` or even have the string be represented as a char array as in Java, and then convert all chars `to_i`

As you can see, I do not have a delimiter as such `,` in the String, all other answers I found on SO included a delimiting char.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple one liner would be:

```
s.each_char.map(&:to_i)
#=> [2, 3, 5, 3, 4]
```

If you want it to be error explicit if the string is not contained of just integers, you could do:

```
s.each_char.map { |c| Integer(c) }
```

This would raise an `ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer():` if your string contained something else than integers.  Otherwise for `.to_i` you would see zeros for characters.

Answer (score 5):

Short and simple:

```
"23534".split('').map(&:to_i)
```

Explanation:

```
"23534".split('') # Returns an array with each character as a single element.

"23534".split('').map(&:to_i) # shortcut notation instead of writing down a full block, this is equivalent to the next line

"23534".split('').map{|item| item.to_i }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String#each_char`:

```
array = []
s.each_char {|c| array << c.to_i }
array
#=> [2, 3, 5, 3, 4]
```

Or just `s.each_char.map(&:to_i)`

Comment: ahhhh each_char to the rescue ... exactly what I overlooked in the string api ...

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple way, we can achieve it this.

1. `'12345'.chars.map(&:to_i)`
2. `'12345'.split("").map(&:to_i)`
3. `'12345'.each_char.map(&:to_i)`
4. `'12345'.scan(/\w/).map(&:to_i)`

I like 3rd one the most. More expressive and simple.

Comment: `'23534'.to_i.digits.reverse`

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9.3 you can do the following to convert a String of Numbers to an Array of Numbers:

Without a space after the comma of split(',') you get this:
"1,2,3".split(',') # => ["1","2","3"]

With a space after the comma of split(', ') you get this:
"1,2,3".split(', ') # => ["1,2,3"]

Without a space after the comma of split(',') you get this:
"1,2,3".split(',').map(&:to_i) # => [1,2,3]

With a space after the comma of split(', ') you get this:
"1,2,3".split(', ').map(&:to_i) # => [1]